# printf creates no or wrong output

Tags: c, stream, printf, buffer, console-application

I wrote a program and for the debugging purposes I want to write some text into the console. Now I found a really weird error and can't find a solution. Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    char input[50];
    char check = 'a';
    for(int i=0; check != EOF; ++i){
        check = scanf("%s", input);
        printf("%s\n",input);
    }

    fflush(stdout);

    char* myAnswer = createList();
    printf("%s\n", myAnswer);

    return 0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

char* createList(){
    char* msg = malloc(6*sizeof(char));
    msg[0]='A';
    msg[1]='B';
    msg[2]='C';
    msg[3]='D';
    msg[4]='E';
    msg[5]='\0';
    return msg;
}
```

the for loop works fine, but "ABCDE" is never written. Instead, sometimes the last word I saved in input is written in the console a second time, missing the last letter. Or it is nothing written at all.
I tried to solve it by flushing the buffer or setting it to zero size. But nothing helped me. I work with Qt Creator, could the error be in my IDE?

Comment: `scanf()` returns an `int`. not a `char`

Comment: thanks, I changed that. But it does not effect the output

Comment: its working fine for me.. add a prototype for your function.

Comment: @Jonas Stop checking for `EOF` , check if `scanf` returns `1` or not . If not then `scanf` failed .

Comment: @Haris yes , if it Is successful it will return 1 .

Comment: Is that related to my problem?

Comment: @Haris I am afraid not . That's not what `scanf` returns . It returns number of arguments successful matched -http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: you never exit the for loop, for example if you put inside the loop something like that if (input[0] == 'q') break; it will exit.

Comment: That could be my mistake, I use 'strg+c' to simulate an EOF. But without a printf in the for loop, it worked as expected

Comment: the expression: `sizeof(char)`  is defined in the standard as 1.   Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  The expression just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that expression.     When calling `malloc()` `realloc()` or `calloc()`,  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding this line: `check = scanf("%s", input);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter) to assure the operation was successful.  In this case use: `if( 1 != scanf( "%49s", input ) ) {// handle error}   2) the "%s" will allow the user to overrun the `input` buffer.  Suggest setting a max length modifier of 1 less than the length of `input`  I.E. "%49s"

Comment: this line: `char check = 'a';` should be `int check;`.   Strongly suggest reading/understanding the man pages for the system functions that are called

Comment: this is what the man page says about the returned value from `scanf()` " These  functions  return the number of input items successfully matched
       and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in the
       event of an early matching failure.

       The  value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either
       the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs.   EOF  is
       also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error indicator
       for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is  set  indicate  the
       error."

Comment: in the posted code, this line: `setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` is completely unnecessary.   When calling` printf()`, if the format string ends with '\n' then the output is immediately flushed.    So the call to `fflush(stdiout);` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: the posted code is missing a couple of key items: `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` and the prototype for the createlist function: `char* createList( void );, all should be in the code before the declaration of `main()` function.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings.

Comment: the posted code is using a `magic` number.  `magic` numbers make the code much harder to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using #define or enum to declare a meaningful name for  the `magic` number and using that meaningful name throughout the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected some parts of your code (like breaking your loop on EOF, changing data type to int etc.). Please see if the following code works. You need to press Ctrl-D after the last input to ensure that the loop breaks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* createList();

int main(void)
{
    setvbuf (stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    char input[50];
    for(;;){
        if (fgets(input, 50, stdin) == NULL)
            break;
        printf("%s\n",input);
    }

    fflush(stdout);

    char* myAnswer = createList();
    printf("%s\n", myAnswer);

    return 0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

char* createList(){
    char* msg = (char *) malloc(6*sizeof(char));
    msg[0]='A';
    msg[1]='B';
    msg[2]='C';
    msg[3]='D';
    msg[4]='E';
    msg[5]='\0';
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: strg+D just writes a '^D' in the console

Comment: this answer has not got all the errors fixed.  The user can overrun the input buffer (because there is no max length modifier on the format string for `scanf()`.)  This results in undefined behaviour and can result in a seg fault event.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Just tried to fix the reported issue. Based on your feedback, I am editing code to replace scanf with fgets,

Answer (score 0):

the following code

```
1) eliminates the code clutter
2) checks for errors
3) compiles cleanly
4) when user input <CTRL-D> (linux) then program receives a EOF

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_INPUT_LEN (50)

char *createList(void);

int main(void)
{
    char input[MAX_INPUT_LEN];


    while(  1 == scanf("%49s", input) )
    {
        printf("%s\n",input);
    }


    char* myAnswer = createList();
    printf("%s\n", myAnswer);

    return 0;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

char* createList(){
    char* msg = malloc(6);
    if( NULL == msg )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    msg[0]='A';
    msg[1]='B';
    msg[2]='C';
    msg[3]='D';
    msg[4]='E';
    msg[5]='\0';
    return msg;
}
```